# Remote branch ahead of local one, not sure how it happened?

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a feature branch and last week made a pull request.

Since then I've modified some files and committed, and now when I push I get the "updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart" message.

I can pull, merge and try again, but what I don't get is how that happened?  I'm the only person using the branch, how did the remote version get ahead of what I'm using locally?  I don't recall backing out any commits...

Comment: Find the diff log of your local and remote branch, and see which commit is missing in local.

Comment: Could it be just the merge commit?

Comment: try `git log origin/branch --not branch` where `origin` is the name of the remote you do the PR at, assuming the feature branch is called `branch` both locally and remotely.

Answer (score 1):

As Francis Colas said, it is the merged pull request that made a commit.

On GitHub anytime you make a pull request and merge through their web UI, a new commit is created that is a merge commit of the two branches (even if it is a fast-forward merge GitHub will still do a merge commit).

This is beneficial to a workflow on GitHub because the merge commit will tag the pull request in its commit message and the commit will show up when you look at the pull request. Typically git won't put a merge commit if its a fast-forward but then there wouldn't be a way to tag the pull request without changing the commit hash.